# After login/out 10 times, Google oauth2Client getToken returns invalid_grant, Bad Request

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

I have a nodejs server implements Google OAuth2 for user authentication. Right after the server starts, users can start to login. However, after **login/out 10 times**, the `oauth2Client.getToken(code)` function will start to stuck, and return the error `{ error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Bad Request' }` eventually. Restart the server, and the login/out works for 10 more times.

Following is the code for user authentication.

```
// index.js

// Node version: Docker, node:alpine
// googleapis Version: 46.0.0

const { google } = require("googleapis");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
  process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI // http://localhost:3000/signin-google
);

app.get("/signin", (req, res) => {
  const url = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "openid"
    ].join(" ")
  });
  res.json({ url });
});

app.get("/signin-google", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { code } = req.query;
    const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    const oauth2 = google.oauth2("v2");
    const {
      data: { email, id: google_id }
    } = await oauth2.userinfo.v2.me.get({
      auth: oAuth2Client
    });
    const myOwnToken = ...
    res.redirect(`${process.env.WEB_BASE_URL}/signin?token=${myOwnToken}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
  }
});
```

It's so weird! Seems like I miss some limit issues but... just can't figure it out! Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god I'm soooo troll, this error is totally not caused by the Google OAuth, it's just because I forgot to close the database connection.